# Impact of adding Hbase region server (Cloudera CDH)

Tags: hbase, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I have a few HBase nodes running in my cluster.
Recently a fresh node has been added to the cluster.

I'm not sure what the impact of this new region server will be.
Will this node even have data, do I need to run compaction for data to populate this machine?
Or is it as simple as adding the service, fire and forget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some regions will be moved to new nodes (Region Server), but the data (stored in HFile on hdfs) will still located at the same place. To serve a request,   new region servers will call another machine to read data from HFile . After compaction data will be stored locally. My advise if you will have enough hdfs space on old machine and you can wait until a compaction happen, you can just add a new servers to your cluster.  But if you want to rebalance your data between old and new machines for some reason, you can force a major compaction. After it, data belonging to new nodes will be moved to new machines.